# MySQL Запрос с подзапросом SUM и сравнить

Tags: mysql

Приветствую товарищи, помогите пожалуйста составить следующий запрос:
Вывести всех продавцов, которые продали больше за месяц чем продавец “Иванов”.
Данные имеются только за один месяц[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался что-то сделать: получилось подобное и ошибка 1111:

```
SELECT l_name FROM sales
WHERE SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) > ANY (
    SELECT SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale)
    FROM sales
    WHERE l_name = 'Ivanov'
)
AND l_name <> 'Ivanov';
```

Comment: `ошибка 1111` -  а что в тексте ошибки написано?

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: функцию sum() нельзя использовать в where, т.к. эта часть запроса выполняется _до_ группировки. можете использовать фразу having и `any` тут не нужен, потому что подзапрос возвращает заведомо только один результат. в основном запросе разумеется должен быть group by

Comment: А что значит "за месяц"? то есть с 1 числа по текущее или за последние 30 дней или что? Это вообще сейчас имеет значение?

Comment: В таблице данные только за один месяц, это не несёт смысловой нагрузки просто необходимо узнать по всей таблице кто продал больше чем Иванов

Comment: SELECT l_name 
FROM sales 
HAVING SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) > ANY ( 
SELECT SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) 
FROM sales 
WHERE l_name = 'Ivanov');

Comment: @Подозрительныйкот написал ответ..... ANY не нужен)

Comment: SELECT l_name FROM sales HAVING SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) > ( SELECT SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) FROM sales WHERE l_name = 'Ivanov');
Всё получилось, спасибо

Comment: Обрати внимание, что нужен GROUP BY, иначе у тебя выведется только одна запись

Comment: У меня и так и так одна запись выводится.
Если с GROUP BY то Васечкин, без GROUP BY Петров

Comment: Всё разобрался проверил сколько MAX по каждому продавцу(их 4). Запрос в итоге с GROUP BY нужен т.к. Васечкин 35к, Иванов 34к, Петров 27к

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT l_name 
FROM `sales`
WHERE user_name <> "Ivanov"
GROUP BY l_name
HAVING SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale) > (
    SELECT SUM(the_amount_of_the_sale)
    FROM `sales`
    WHERE l_name ="Ivanov"
)
```

Но это не учитывает тот  самый мифический месяц

и, в принципе, вполне работает без `WHERE user_name <> "Ivanov"`, ведь иванова мы итак отсеиваем в неравенстве в  having